# Is there a "smart cache" device which provides cache if authorized?

Tags: network, http, authorization, caching

Is there an implementation of a HTTP (or decoded HTTPS) optimization device which would allow for "smart caching" - i.e. the ability to release some cached content (initially transferred by someone else) provided that the requester is authorized to access some data. 
The distant optimization device could for instance query the authorization for specific, cached data (small requests) and release the cache (significant data) if the authorization is correct.

This question arose while reading about optimization boxes (specifically [Riverbed SteelHead HTTP optimization](https://support.riverbed.com/bin/support/static/hqs5redbo2blgk6d8tlejhstvk/html/fidl3j3el34d14ou0h1hvktt8f/sh_9.1_dg_protocols_html/index.html#page/sh_9.1_dg_protocols%2Fhttp.06.04.html%23wwconnect_header), but it is just an example of the kind of devices I have in mind) and I could not find anything via searches.

Comment: You could probably implement something like this into your application, but it's unlikely that a generic device could work very well - the data for each application is likely to be very distinct, so configuration would be very complex. The alternative would be a CDN to get data locally, and to generate links to that data based on authorisation, although there is no way to ensure that is the only way to generate such links.

Comment: @Matthew: yes, I realize that the data will be very different, this is why my idea was around checking the authorization remotely (in a data-generic way, just check if specific data would be made available or blocked), and release it locally if authorized. I did not find any implementation but it might have been hidden in some configuration options for intermediate boxes (of the SteelHead kind). Thanks.